# Reading output of last code cell in .net interactive (polyglot notebooks)?

Tags: c#, .net, interactive, dotnet-interactive, polyglot-notebooks

I like to write a test for the output of the last code cell. How can I get the output of the last code cell or any code cell in the c# notebook? The FAQ of .net interactive mentions the Microsoft.DotNet.Interactive.Documents-Class. But I am not sure how to use it.